# Generated moc names are not correct

Tags: qt, qt4, cmake, qobject, metaobject

I am working on a Qt based project that uses cmake. All of my generated moc files are named `*.moc`, but I have some files that their generated moc files have names `moc_*.cpp`, not `*.moc`. Why this happens and how I can fix these files.

**EDIT:**

- I want to say that these classes are inheriting from QObject and has the Q_OBJECT and Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC macros, and they don't compile with me unless there is a .moc for them.
- I must include the .moc files in my .cpp files.

**- The thing that makes me go crazy that I have an identical class (identical implementation to my class) that generates a .moc but my class generate moc_*.cpp.**

Comment: Your files belonging to those moc files which are named `*.moc`, do they consist of both a `*.h` and a `*.cpp`? The `*.moc` files (not the `moc_*.cpp` files), are they put in the build or the source directory?

Comment: Just for explanation in my cmakelist files I add the .cpp file which make both .h and .cpp compiled well and in my .cpp I include the .moc file only with no .h, the moc_*.cpp are generated in the same build directory that .moc are generated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to include *.moc file in every case of Q_OBJECT use. .moc files are generated only for classes that are declared in .cpp files. In other cases moc generates moc_*.cpp that includes your Q_OBJECT based class on it's own. You don't have anything to be worried about. Remove *.moc includes from your cpp files. for example:

main.cpp

```
class E: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
};
```

moc will generate main.moc file to be included in main.cpp

Another example

class.h

```
class E: public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     void member();
};
```

class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

void E::member()
{
}
```

moc will generate moc_class.cpp that includes class.h and is separate compilation unit

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the compiler gives me "undefined reference to " my constructor and the functions it this class. It  compiles fine without the Q_OBJECT macro. What do you think.

Comment: Also I want to say that in my project there is another class that has similar implementation and it compiles fine and generates a .moc. I don't know why this class generate moc_*.cpp instead.

Comment: sorry, I don't know the reason of that behaviour. I remember that I've used Qt with cmake without any problem. You're doing something wrong here. Do you have Qt cmake modules?

Comment: The rest of the project classes are behaving just fine, my problem is that why this class that is very similar to the other fine classes not generating a .moc file.

Comment: because as I said it should (and it does) generate moc_*.cpp that should be automaticly added as source file